# "Could not find method packageName()" Error in RC1 - Flavors do not compile

Tags: android, android-studio

The project which was built in the previous versions of **Android Studio** does not want to compile in the latest **RC1.**

The project uses flavors and I keep getting message:

> Could not find method packageName() for arguments [org.XXYYZZ.apps] on GroupableProductFlavor_Decorated{name=english, minSdkVersion=null, targetSdkVersion=null, renderscriptTargetApi=null, renderscriptSupportModeEnabled=null, renderscriptNdkModeEnabled=null, versionCode=null, versionName=null, applicationId=null, testApplicationId=null, testInstrumentationRunner=null, testHandleProfiling=null, testFunctionalTest=null, signingConfig=null, resConfig=null, mBuildConfigFields={}, mResValues={}, mProguardFiles=[], mConsumerProguardFiles=[], mManifestPlaceholders={}}.

It seems that it breaks on the first flavor name as it's unable to use its method `packageName`.

Gradle version is

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.14.4'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'
...
```

What could be causing this error? Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

PackageName is deprecated, it isn't supported anymore by the new Gradle plugin used in RC1.
Use "applicationId" instead of "packageName" attribute.

[Changes listed here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system)

Comment: You mean Gradle 0.14.4. It makes sense. I will check.

Comment: Yes, Gradle 0.14.4 is the plugin version used by Android Studio 1.0 RC1 ;)

Comment: Worked! Had to change packageName->applicationId and runProguard->minifyEnabled. It's bad that Android Studio simply reports errors and not offer you solution like it does usually.

Comment: yes, I had the same errors. I think they won't be changing these attributes again, it was just a Beta, but now they try to simplify everything just before the release.